# VSTO Outlook strange behavior modifying mail body

Tags: email, outlook, vsto

I got a rather strange situation going on. I am modifying the mail contents with these parts of code for newly composed e-mails. It works flawlesly in all the different environments I have encountered so far.

```
     MailItem _currentItem; // this is assigned
     private void InsertAtCursor(string html)
            {
                html = ReplaceCID(html);
    
                Word.Document xDoc = _currentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
                var xSel = xDoc.Application.Selection;
    
                ClipboardHelper.CopyToClipboard(html);
    
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
    
                xSel.PasteSpecial();
    
                int i = xSel.Start += html.Length;
                xSel.SetRange(i, i);
    
                xDoc = null;
                xSel = null;
            }
    
            private void InsertAtTop(string html)
            {
                InsertCID(html);
    
                _currentItem.HTMLBody = html + _currentItem.HTMLBody;
            }
```

For one user these lines of code do not seem to work. Meaning that the HTML is not written away in the mail body - I can confirm the mail body is in HTML format. You can alternate by inserting at top or inserting at cursor. My code handles in case the InsertAtCursor generates an exception, fall back to InsertAtTop. I always save the mail item when the codes handles it OK or an exception should occur.

My question: Are there any security policies for Outlook and/or settings that may block writing to `HtmlBody`?

**Edit:**

Got the same result using the following line of code, works for nearly all clients I tested, except for one.

```
public class Test
{
    private MailItem _currentItem;

    public Test(MailItem item)
    {
        _currentItem = item;
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        _currentItem.Body = "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: What line of code gives an exception? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: No exception is thrown unfortunately, I cannot replicate this behavior in my own environment (and debug) as it only happens with a very select few of systems. Hence the question does Outlook have any security practices / settings in place that might cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML back - the two must be merged. At least in InsertAtTop().

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I was thinking more in the lines of some plugin / security setting that blocks it. I have yet to research it myself, but it seems that Macro support / protection has something to do with it (GPO was in place). Outlook is perfectly capable to handle the 'faulty' html, never had issues with it.

Comment: It can handle misformed HTML up to a point - sooner or later it breaks. Why take any chances?

Comment: You are right about that, I can look further into that but it would not explain why the same HTML works in the majority of most other environments. Are you aware though of any requirements that may cause a VSTO plugin and especially mail (HTML) body updates to malfunction? E.g. macro security settings, dependencies with another plugin like Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin?

Comment: Don't take any chances and do the right thing - create a well formed HTML document.

Comment: Okay, well in that instance got now another alike issuee but then with plain-text. Are there any security checks that could prevent modifying the mail body?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The mail body itself refuses to be set (or update itself). In my test so far I tried mail.Body = "Test", code gets called, no exception but refuses to update the mail body. I was thinking this has something to do with the security settings under trust center. But I cannot find any difference on that part with for example my own settings. This test works on other clients.

Comment: You might want to start a new thread and post the relevant snippets of your code.

Comment: I updated the original question with the relevant code, as I felt this relates to my original question.

Comment: Where does _currentItem come from? Do you ever call _currentItem.Save?

Comment: I always call _currentItem.Save().

Comment: So the question still remain where _currentItem comes from and where you expect to see the change.

Comment: The _currentItem can either be assigned from the on-send event or manually from a ribbon action. I know these selections work properly, I read for example the recipients before the above code is called which works flawlessly. After I assign a new body, insert at cursor or insert at top, I'd expect after the _currentItem.Save() to see the modified mail body.

Comment: As a test, do modifications to other properties (e.g. Subject) persist?

Comment: I have not tried to modify the subject or something else, could try that as well. Will get back to you, as I need to schedule something to test it on the client.